# backward elimination/forward selection in multilinear regression in Julia

Tags: regression, julia, linear-regression

I'm quite new to Julia.

Is there a package in Julia which helps in automating the backward or forward elimination of features for a multiple linear regression problem.

I have found the code in python [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48573261/1861349) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29835822/1861349) but not able to find any in Julia.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given no response there is probably no support :). The reason is most likely that typically Lasso etc. are preferred to forward/backward selection. And you have support for regularization e.g. in Regression.jl.

However, it is pretty simple to write your own step-wise selection:

```
using DataFrames
using RDatasets
using StatsBase
using GLM

function compose(lhs::Symbol, rhs::AbstractVector{Symbol})
    Formula(lhs, Expr(:call, :+, [1;rhs]...))
end

function step(df, lhs::Symbol, rhs::AbstractVector{Symbol},
              forward::Bool, use_aic::Bool)
    options = forward ? setdiff(names(df), [lhs; rhs]) : rhs
    fun = use_aic ? aic : bic
    isempty(options) && return (rhs, false)
    best_fun = fun(lm(compose(lhs, rhs), df))
    improved = false
    best_rhs = rhs
    for opt in options
        this_rhs = forward ? [rhs; opt] : setdiff(rhs, [opt])
        this_fun = fun(lm(compose(lhs, this_rhs), df))
        if this_fun < best_fun
            best_fun = this_fun
            best_rhs = this_rhs
            improved = true
        end
    end
    (best_rhs, improved)
end

function stepwise(df, lhs::Symbol, forward::Bool, use_aic::Bool)
    rhs = forward ? Symbol[] : setdiff(names(df), [lhs])
    while true
        rhs, improved = step(df, lhs, rhs, forward, use_aic)
        improved || return lm(compose(lhs, sort(rhs)), df)
    end
end
```

Two key parameters above are `forward` (do we do forward or backward selection) and `use_aic` (do we use AIC or BIC). Of course all this can be easily changed. The implementation is not optimized for speed, but should be good enough in simple cases.

Here is how can you use it:

```
df = dataset("datasets", "swiss")[2:end]
stepwise(df, :Fertility, true, false)
stepwise(df, :Fertility, true, true)
stepwise(df, :Fertility, false, true)
stepwise(df, :Fertility, false, false)
```

(all options return the same model and are consistent with a reference example in R)

Comment: Thanks @bogumil !

Comment: Hey @bogumil, it is possible to do the same thing but using **Tensorflow** instead ? My client wants to use tensorflow moving ahead and wants one input as **The number of significant variables (specified by the user)**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The general framework will be the same. The difference is that for Tensorflow and your problem: 1) `compose` function will be different, 2) model estimation will be different and 3) stopping criterion will be different. But in general the requirement you state is very unusual and probably not optimal (a particular question is how categorical variables should be counted).

Comment: Stumbled into the same problem. Will be using this answer. Thanks @BogumiłKamiński

Comment: Hi everyone, I'm trying to do this, but it appears the `Formula` constructor function no longer works this way (but rather uses a macro). I've gotten it to work by creating the X and y matrices myself, but it loses the names of the columns passed in. Anyone know any ways to use @formula programmatically?

Comment: Now it is: https://juliastats.org/StatsModels.jl/latest/formula/#Constructing-a-formula-programmatically-1